# Bold text in LibreOffice using macros (LibreOffice Basic)

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I am doctor (X-ray). Asking my friend to create text macros for me to write protocols faster.
I just wanted to push ALT+Q (or another letter). Then push ALT+number (from 0 to 9).
For each ALT+number I insert prepared text.
It is work.
Part of inserted text should be bold. I insert text, then select 2-3 words and press Ctrl+B.
But I wanted to customised macro.

I need:
vvod(0).Value = //bold "Вариант строения bold// — // regular один корень, один канал. regular//"

I tried to figure it out on my own, but I can't, because I'm a piece of shit.
Can someone tell me in which direction to think, because I'm stuck?

I am attaching part of the code.

```
enter code here

    REM ***** BASIC ***** 

GLOBAL number as Integer 
GLOBAL vid as Integer 
public Sub Main 
End Sub 

public Sub ALTQ 
vid = 1 
End Sub 

public Sub ALTW 
vid = 2 
End Sub 

public Sub ALTE
vid = 3 
End Sub 

public sub ALT1 
number = 1 
solve() 
end sub 

public sub ALT2 
number = 2 
solve() 
end sub 

public sub ALT3 
number = 3 
solve() 
end sub 

public sub solve 
rem —-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------— 
rem Определение переменных и получение доступа к ним, не трогай 
dim document as object 
dim dispatcher as object 
document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame 
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper") 
rem —---------------------------------------------------------— 
rem определение переменных, которые ты сам будешь создавать и использовать 
dim vvod(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue 
rem Name обязательно равняется ТЕКСТ 
vvod(0).Name = "Text" 
rem —------------------------------------------------------------------------------------— 

if vid = 1 Then 
if number = 1 Then 
vvod(0).Value = "коронковая часть реставрирована. " 
elseif number = 2 Then 
vvod(0).Value = "коронковая часть реставрирована пломбами. " 
elseif number = 3 Then 
vvod(0).Value = "депульпирован. Коронковая часть реставрирована. " 
End if
```

---

I tried to figure it out myself and this is what I came up with:

1)

```
Dim sVar As String
sVar = "Это тест"
sVar.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
```

error

2)

```
Dim TextX As Object
TextX.String = "Это тест"
RectangleShape.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
vvod(0).Value = TextX
```

error

---

I will be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to give exact details because I don't use Libreoffice Basic but in `python` you need to grab the `cursor` and apply the font attributes to that.
i.e. something along the lines of:

```
desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
cursor = desktop.getCurrentComponent().getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
oFontWeight = cursor.CharWeight
Text_Weight = FontWeight.BOLD
cursor.CharWeight=Text_Weight
text.insertString(cursor, insert_text, 0)
cursor.CharWeight=oFontWeight
```

In principle, grab the current cursor and make a note of the current setting.
Apply **Bold** text to the cursor
Insert text using the adjusted cursor
Reset cursor to previous text setting, or everything after this will be **Bold**.

p.s. I'm still grinning at your description of yourself. Good luck!

The above assumes:

```
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
text = model.Text
```

and that you imported `com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight`